# About the behavior of go routine in go routine

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm newie to golang and studying the goroutine.
I wrote the simple code that divide the number using goroutine on purpose.
First of all, I give the base number and keep on dividing its number until it is not divisible
But, I change `go split(n)` to `split(n)`, it is not working like the following, is this why?

■ source code

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

var next = make(chan int)
var quit = make(chan int)

func divide(n int) {
    defer func(){ quit <- 1 }()

    fmt.Println("[divide] n = " + strconv.Itoa(n))

    r := n % 2
    if r == 0 {
        next <- n / 2
    }
}

func execute() {

    fmt.Println("[execute] start")
    count := 0
    end   := false
    for !end {
        select {
        case n := <- next:
            count++
            fmt.Println("[execute] n = " + strconv.Itoa(n) + ", count = " + strconv.Itoa(count))
            go divide(n)
        case _ = <- quit:
            count--
            fmt.Println("[execute] end. count = " + strconv.Itoa(count))
            if count <= 0 {
                end = true
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("complete")
    os.Exit(0)
}

func main() {

    base := flag.Int("n", 1, "Input the number")
    flag.Parse()

    if *base <= 0 {
        fmt.Println("please more than 1")
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    go execute()
    next <- *base

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndSearver:", err)
    }
}
```

■ result(work fine)

```
$ go run main.go -n 6
[execute] start
[execute] n = 6, count = 1
[divide] n = 6
[execute] n = 3, count = 2
[execute] end. count = 1
[divide] n = 3
[execute] end. count = 0
complete
```

■ result(not work)

```
$ go run main.go -n 6
[execute] start
[execute] n = 6, count = 1
[divide] n = 6
```

Comment: Without the goroutine `next <- n / 2` blocks because there's nothing reading from `next`, why is nothing reading from `next`? because `divide` didn't exist, why? because it's waiting for `next <- n / 2` to stop blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `go divide()` inside execute:

- execute() reads from the `next` channel, calls `divide`
- divide() waits to write to `next`
- execute() is still waiting for divide() to return, so program is now deadlocked.

With `go divide()` inside execute:

- execute() reads from the `next` channel, starts `divide` in new goroutine, continues waiting
- divide() writes to `next`
- execute() reads from `next`, starts another goroutine, etc.

Note that as soon as `divide` writes to `next`, it continues to write to `quit` so you may receive multiple quit messages before everything is done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question.
`divide() waits to write to next`
Why is this waiting for writing to next when calls divide without goroutine ?

Comment: A write to a channel blocks until another goroutine reads from it. It is a synchronization mechanism.

Comment: Oh, I understand!
Because there was not a channel to be able to write, I need to make a new goroutine ?

Comment: Without the goroutine, write to `next` blocks, because the read from that channel is also in that same goroutine.